# attempting to exceed the max dequeued buffer count (12)

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm building a app camera (api2), i show camera preview, capture and after show image.

It worked but my logcat have error:

```
dequeueBuffer: attempting to exceed the max dequeued buffer count (12)
```

This my code camera prevew:

```
fun cameraPreview(){
    if(camOutputSizeWidth > camOutputSizeHeight){
        val layoutParam = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(widthPixels,(widthPixels*camOutputSizeWidth)/(camOutputSizeHeight))
        mytextureView.layoutParams = layoutParam
    }else{
        val layoutParam = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(widthPixels,(widthPixels*camOutputSizeHeight)/(camOutputSizeWidth))
        mytextureView.layoutParams = layoutParam
    }

    val texture = mytextureView.surfaceTexture
    texture.setDefaultBufferSize(camOutputSizeWidth, camOutputSizeWidth)

    val surface  = Surface(texture)
    captureRequestBuilder = mCamera.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW)
    captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface)
    mCamera.createCaptureSession(arrayListOf(surface),CameraPreviewSessionCallback(), null)
}
```

Why is that error? How to do fix it?

Comment: Hi, smae here, did you solve it ?